# Verify/prove recursive expression involving sums over permutations and their signs

Tags: summation, permutations, recursion, symmetric-groups

Given a sequence of vectors $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ with $(\forall i \in \{ 1, 2, ... \} ) a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is the following equation true, and furthermore is it possible to formally prove that it is true?

$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_{j-1}}{\left[\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{l=1}^{j-1}{\left[ a_l^T a_{\sigma(l))} \right ]}  \left( a_j^Ta_j - \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}{\left[ \frac{\left( a_j^T a_k \right ) \left(a_{\sigma(k)}^T a_j \right )}{a_k^T a_{\sigma(k)} } \right ]} \right ) \right ]} = \sum_{\sigma\in S_{j}}{\left[\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{l=1}^{j}{\left[ a_l^T a_{\sigma(l))} \right ]} \right ]}$$

For example, with $j=3$:

$$ \begin{aligned}
&\sum_{\sigma\in S_{2}}{\left[\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{l=1}^{2}{\left[ a_l^T a_{\sigma(l))} \right ]}  \left( a_3^T a_3 - \sum_{k=1}^{2}{\left[ \frac{\left( a_3^T a_k \right ) \left(a_{\sigma(k)}^T a_3 \right )}{a_k^T a_{\sigma(k)} } \right ]} \right ) \right ]} \\\\
&=+(a_1^T a_1)(a_2^T a_2) \left( a_3^T a_3 - \frac{( a_3^T a_1 ) (a_1^T a_3 )}{a_1^T a_1 } - \frac{( a_3^T a_2 ) (a_2^T a_3 )}{a_2^T a_2 } \right ) - (a_1^T a_2)(a_2^T a_1) \left( a_3^T a_3 - \frac{( a_3^T a_1 ) (a_2^T a_3 )}{a_1^T a_2 } - \frac{( a_3^T a_2 ) (a_1^T a_3 )}{a_2^T a_1 } \right ) \\\\
&= + (a_1^T a_1) (a_2^T a_2) (a_3^T a_3) - (a_1^T a_3) (a_2^T a_2) (a_3^T a_1) - (a_1^T a_1) (a_2^T a_3) (a_3^T a_2) - (a_1^T a_2) (a_2^T a_1) (a_3^T a_3) + (a_1^T a_3) (a_2^T a_1) (a_3^T a_2) + (a_1^T a_2) (a_2^T a_3) (a_3^T a_1) \\\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{3}}{\left[\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{l=1}^{3}{\left[ a_l^T a_{\sigma(l))} \right ]} \right ]} \end{aligned} $$

It seems intuitively plausible to me that this equation is true (indeed, it's clear that there are the correct number of terms on each side of the equation, and the denominators all cancel out), although I'm not sure how to prove it.

EDIT: I'm looking for answers that don't involve matrix determinants. For an explanation of this, and the general motivation for this question, see the comments below on this question.

EDIT 2: Note to self: a useful approach might be to start with the RHS and write the sum $\sum_{\sigma\in S_j}$ as two sums $\sum_{\sigma\in S_j: \sigma(j) = j}$ and $\sum_{\sigma\in S_j: \sigma(j) \ne j}$, factorise terms including $a_j$ outside of the product of inner products, write $\sum_{\sigma\in S_j: \sigma(j) \ne j}$ as $\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\sum_{\sigma\in S_j: \sigma(j) = k}$, simplify and then rewrite in terms of $S_{j-1}$, accounting for the change in sign of the permutations which don't fix $j$.

Or, slightly simpler, write $\sum_{\sigma\in S_j}$ as $\sum_{k=1}^{j}\sum_{\sigma\in S_j: \sigma(j) = k}$ - later the $\sum_{k=1}^{j}$ can be split up and an $a_j^T a_j$ term will hopefully cancel in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: How did you come across this identity without a way to prove it???

Comment: Good question! If we consider the sequence of vectors given in the question, and define a set of unnormalised basis vectors $q_i = a_i - \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}{\left[ \left( \frac{a_i^T q_j}{a_j^T q_j} \right) q_j \right] }$, I think I've found an expression for $q_i$ in terms of $(a_j)_{j=1}^{i}$ only (IE eliminating the other basis vectors), and I'm trying to prove that it's true by induction

Comment: Ah, so Gram-Schmidt, that makes sense. This is apparently known and the answer does indeed involve Gram determinants: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#Determinant_formula

Comment: This problem in turn comes from trying to find the $m$-dimensional volume of the parallelotope defined by the vectors $(a_i)_{i=1}^{m}$ (IE the $m$-dimensional parallelotope with vertices at the origin, each of these vectors, their sum, etc) $= \prod_{i=1}^{m}{\sqrt{q_i^T q_i}}$. The ultimate idea is to use this expression for the volume to derive the Leibniz formula for the determinant - hence I'm looking for answers that don't use properties of determinants (as this would lead to circular reasoning in the solution to the overall problem) - I forgot to mention this in the question, sorry!

Comment: It's always a good idea to describe your actual motivation for asking a question for exactly this reason!

Comment: This bit of the Wikipedia article on Gram matrices also seems relevant (and doesn't directly use determinants): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix#Constructing_an_orthonormal_basis

Comment: Thank you! That does look interesting, I imagine $G^{1/2}$ could easily be computed using an eigenvalue decomposition and taking the square roots of the eigenvalues (or similar), although I'm not sure how to find an expression for $G^{1/2}$ in general

Comment: That's how you do it in general.

Answer (score 1):

The RHS is the determinant of the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) $\det(a_i^T a_j)$. The LHS should be obtained from the RHS via a cofactor expansion along either the last row or the last column, although this is somewhat disguised by how you've written it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've made an edit to the question, specifying I'm looking for answers that don't involve matrix determinants (for anyone else reading this comment, see the comments on the original question for an explanation)